# Process items in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a FileSystemWatcher which looks for files in a folder. Moment the file is created a Created event is fired. I am adding each created file name to a queue.

```
void Main(){
            FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fsw.Path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToDataFolder"];
            //fsw.Filter = "*.docx";
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Created);
}
private void fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
            queue.Enqueue(e.FullPath);    
}
```

Overtime the files will increase and the queue will become large. So the queue is dynamic. I want to process each file in parallel. But I dont want to process a lot of files at once because that is quite resource intensive. Once a file is processed i want to dequeue it and pick another file to process.

How can i achieve this in C#?

Comment: You can choose to only dequeue a certain number of items at once, right?

Comment: You are looking for producer / consumer pattern; please, take a glance at `BlockingCollection` (instead of `Queue` which is *not* thread safe)

Comment: yes dequeue certain number of items but also keep track of how many threads are running in parallel. Number of active threads must be less than some value

Comment: thanks...i am reading about producer/consumer pattern

Comment: The book that realy helps in that questions for me is [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](https://stephencleary.com/book/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-2.1) with a configurable degree of parallelism. By default, an ActionBlock uses only one Task to process incoming messages. You can make it use [multiple tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-specify-the-degree-of-parallelism-in-a-dataflow-block) to process files in parallel. The FSW's event should post paths directly to the block :

```
ActionBlock<string> _block;

void Main()
{

    ...
    var options= new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
     {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
     };

    _block=new ActionBlock<string>(path=>MyPathProcessingFunction(path), options);

   //Configure the FSW as before
}

private void fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    _block.Post(e.FullPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the producer/consumer pattern. In .Net the BlockingCollection class provides support for this pattern. Whenever the event handler is triggered, it will add the path to the queue and also creates a new task to process the queue. So for every monitored file a new task is created. You can change the task creation strategy if you want, and also manage how they are scheduled with the TaskScheduler.

```
public class Watcher
{
    public Watcher()
    {
        _queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();
    }

    private BlockingCollection<string> _queue;

    public void Start()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fsw.Path = @"F:\a";
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        fsw.Created += Fsw_Created;
    }

    private void Fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        _queue.Add(e.FullPath);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var path = _queue.Take();
            // process the queue here
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for *producer / consumer pattern* which in C# can be implemented via [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), e.g.

```
 private static async Task Perform() {
   // Be careful with this parameter: what do you expect the system
   // to do if the pipeline contains pipelineMaxLength items?
   int pipelineMaxLength = 100;
   int consumersCount = 10;

   using (BlockingCollection<string> pipeline = 
     new BlockingCollection<string>(pipelineMaxLength)) {

     // Producer(s)
     using (FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher()) {
       ...
       fsw.Created += (s, e) => {
         // whenever new file has been created, add it to the pipeline 
         if (!pipeline.IsAddingCompleted)
           pipeline.Add(e.FullPath);

         // Whenever you have no files to add and you want quit processing call
         // pipeline.CompleteAdding();
       };

       // Consumers (consumersCount of them are working in parallel)
       var consumers = Enumerable
        .Range(0, consumersCount) // 
        .Select(index => Task.Run(() => {
           // each consumer extracts file from the pipeline and processes it
           foreach (var file in pipeline.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
             //TODO: process the file here 
           } }))
        .ToArray();

       // (a)wait until all the consumers finish their work
       await Task
         .WhenAll(consumers);
     }
   }
 }
```